# Set description of the group generated by a family of transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $n\geq 0$ be an integer and $(\tau_{i,i+1})_{1\leq i\leq n-1}$ be a family of transpositions of $\mathfrak{S}_{n}$, the symmetric group of the interval $[1,n]$ of $\mathbb{N}$.

What is the set-theoretic description of the group generated by $(\tau_{i,i+1})_{1\leq i\leq n-1}$? Is it

$$\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_{n}\ |\ (\exists\alpha)(\alpha\in X^{[1,m]}\land\sigma=\alpha_1...\alpha_m)\},$$
where $X=\{\gamma\ |\ (\exists i)(i\in[1,n-1]\land\gamma=\tau_{i,i+1})\}$?

Comment: Does $\tau_{i,i+1}$ mean the transposition which swaps $i$ and $i+1$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: These are sometimes called the "elementary transpositions". They generate the whole symmetric group. This is a not so hard exercise, you should try it. (Googling "elementary transposition" can also give you some hints.)